# Recurrence relation general solutions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, relations

how would I go about tackling this kind of question? I'm struggling with the concept of recurrence relations. Any advice would be apreciated.

> Find the general solution of each of the following recurrences.
>
> (a) $u_n = 7u_{n−1} − 12u_{n−2}$
>
> (b) $u_n − 3u_{n−1} = 4n^2$
>
> (c) $u_n − 3u_{n−1} = 5 \cdot 4^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints:*

(a) Try solutions of the form $u_n=a \lambda^n$.

(b) Try solutions of the form $u_n = a 3^n + b n^2 + c n + d$

(c) Try solutions of the form $u_n = a 3^n + b 4^n$

The main principle is to combine solutions of the homogenous equation with a particular solution.

(a) is a homogenous equation and you can just try $u_n=a \lambda^n$ and see which $\lambda^n$ work.

(b) and (c) are not homogenous but their homogenous part is easy. For the particular solution for the non homogenous part, just try something of the same form.

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more, i don't fully understand.

Comment: @reemq8, see my edited answer. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving.